# Gap at bottom of iPad screen

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

I'am porting my app to iOS 7 and when in run it on iPad there is a 20px black gap at bottom of the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Tpw.jpg). This gap is only on iPad..
I try to set bigger UIWindow frame but it doesn't help.

Is there any solution?
Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the status bar area (battery, wifi etc) is now usable and is an 20px.

You'll either need to move your app down by 20px and then deal with the status bar area separately.

Another approach would be to make your view longer e.g. add 20px to your background or scrollview.

Comment: Thanks. I use MGSplitView controller so I simply edit it's code: `float statusBarHeight = ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) ? 0 : MAX((fullScreenRect.size.width - appFrame.size.width), (fullScreenRect.size.height - appFrame.size.height));` And it works perfectly :)